# ab_bottom_solid and ab_solid png patches for actionbar background

Tags: android-theme

Those ".png" (ab_bottom_solid_theme_name.png and ab_solid_theme_name.png) files are generated by Action Bar Style Generator (cannot post link). I also noticed that these files are in the Android sdk default "drawable" folders.

Currently my action bar looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5021052/tmp/download.png) and I want it to be like [this](https://developer.android.com/images/training/basics/actionbar-theme-custom@2x.png). The horizontal line under the ActionBar (ActionBar indicator?) is invisible. How can I make it be like in the second link? Do I have to modify those ".png" files?
Which one to modify in order to have a darker horizontal line just under the ActionBar?
Is there another solution that would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution found. modified the `png`s manually.